# I'm trying to give elevation to corners of cardview

Tags: android, xml, cardview

I'm trying to provide `elevation` to the corners of `cardview`. my requirement is `elevation` should n't effect at the middle of `cardview`. it should effect only corners like image shown below.

[image]

As shown in image, at the middle of the `cardview` `elevation` should be zero at corners there should be some `elevation` (for example:
`elevation:4dp`)

Here is the code i tried so far

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                            android:background="@null"
                                            android:gravity="center"
                                            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                                            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                                            card_view:cardElevation="3dp">
```

Comment: Cardview is not providing such type of elevation

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`

So your xml should look like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp"/>
```

Comment: card should stick to background i.e., elevation should be zero at middle please see the image carefully @mrid

Comment: @Leonardo Cavazzani Please see the image once carefully that image there elevation = 0 at middle how can i do that